# Dequeue Data From Oracle AQ Using Weblogic 10.3.4, JMS and/or Spring?

Tags: jms, weblogic, spring-ws, oracle-aq

Anyone know of a good example that does this?   Seems like a lot of Admin Console configuration (Foreign JNDI Providers?) in Weblogic to make this happen.  I'm a newbie with Spring, but maybe it simplifies things a bit?   Should this be an MDB or WebService - which is a better practice?

Answer (score 0):

[Weblogic Using JMS AQ Bridge](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-aq-in-weblogic-103.html)